# i have six array elements, what usage is better than others, and why?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

i have six variables, what usage is better than others, and why?

```
$a["1"];
$a1['1'];
$a2[1];
$b['b'];
$b1["b"];
$b2[b];
```

question is only about code optimization, can't really understand what of that is better than other

Comment: For integer type variable:  $a2[1];   and for string type  - $b['b'] OR $b1["b"] , quotes don't matter

Comment: Did you try `$a[$b][$b1][$b2][$a1] % INF` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to use the data.

Obviously for strings, if you want it as a string, store it as so. Single vs double quotes don't matter here.

If you plan to use 1 as a number for math or comparison, do `$b1[1]`

`$b2[b]` will break actually because b is not stored as a constant as of right now and it is not a variable or numeric data. Unless you do

`const b = "b"` then `$b2[b]`

Double quotes however allow string interpolation, aka

`$string = "This is a string with a variable $variable in it";`

where

`$string = 'A string $withabrokenvariable';` will not work